# Is there a way to make two flashing objects in turtle graphic work in different situations?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am making in the middle of making a shooting game. I am now working on a mechanism that has two lights flash when the bullet is ready to shoot, and another one to flash when the bullet is somewhere else and cannot be shot. I am using pens as lights, using *hideturtle()* and *showturtle()* to make the pens flash.

```
#Shooting game
import turtle
import time

#Setting up thingies and background
Arena=turtle.Screen()
Arena.bgcolor("lawngreen")
Arena.setup(1000,1000)
Arena.title("BLACK HAS TO BANG WHITE WITH BOMBS")
#Setting up the cannon
Banger=turtle.Pen()
Banger.up()
Banger.shape("square")
Banger.shapesize(2,8)
Banger.goto(-440,-300)
Banger.color("black")
Banger.setheading(180)
#Setting the ready "light"
Ready=turtle.Pen()
Ready.hideturtle()
Ready.up()
Ready.shape("square")
Ready.color("green")
Ready.shapesize(2,2)
Ready.goto(290,300)
#setting the not ready "light"
Notready=turtle.Pen()
Notready.hideturtle()
Notready.up()
Notready.shape("square")
Notready.color("red")
Notready.shapesize(2,2)
Notready.goto(300,300)
#Setting the bullet
Bullet=turtle.Pen()
Bullet.up()
Bullet.shape("circle")
Bullet.shapesize(2)
Bullet.color("darkblue")
Bullet.goto(-440,-300)
Bullet.speed(5)


#Setting up moving and interacting functions
def moveup():
    Banger.left(10)
    Bullet.left(10)
def movedown():
    Banger.right(10)
    Bullet.right(10)
def shoot():
    Bullet.showturtle()
    Bullet.forward(600)
    time.sleep(1)
    Bullet.hideturtle()
    Bullet.goto(-440,-300) 
    
#Setting the signal for the "lights" to react
if Bullet.xcor()==-440 and Bullet.ycor==-300:
    Ready.showturtle()
    Notready.hideturtle()
else:
    Notready.showturtle()
    Ready.hideturtle()    
    
#Setting up the keybinds 
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(moveup,"t")
turtle.onkeypress(movedown,"g")
turtle.onkeypress(shoot,"1")
turtle.mainloop()
```

I have tried many ways like *if and else* statements and even threads. But somehow for me, the "lights" does not even flash once. I have put into lots of time into this, and I really appreciate the help so thanks! :D

Ps. Everything else in this code works, but if you find out any other problems, I would also accept your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have this logic at the *top level* where it can only execute *once* and so does no good:

```
#Setting the signal for the "lights" to react
if Bullet.xcor()==-440 and Bullet.ycor==-300:
    Ready.showturtle()
    Notready.hideturtle()
else:
    Notready.showturtle()
    Ready.hideturtle()
```

We need to integrate it into the bullet logic:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Moving and interacting functions
def moveup():
    banger.left(10)

def movedown():
    banger.right(10)

def shoot():
    screen.onkeypress(None, '1')

    if bullet.isvisible():
        if bullet.distance(banger) > 600:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            ready.color('green')
            screen.onkeypress(shoot, '1')
            return

        bullet.forward(5)
    else:
        ready.color('red')
        bullet.goto(banger.position())
        bullet.setheading(banger.heading())
        bullet.forward(80)
        bullet.showturtle()

    screen.ontimer(shoot, 10)

# Set up screen
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1000, 1000)
screen.bgcolor('lawngreen')
screen.title("BLACK HAS TO BANG WHITE WITH BOMBS")

# Set up the cannon
banger = Turtle()
banger.shape('square')
banger.shapesize(2, 8)
banger.penup()
banger.goto(-440, -300)

# Set up the ready 'light'
ready = Turtle()
ready.shape('square')
ready.shapesize(2)
ready.color('green')
ready.penup()
ready.goto(290, 300)

# Set up the bullet
bullet = Turtle()
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.shape('circle')
bullet.shapesize(2)
bullet.color('darkblue')
bullet.penup()
bullet.speed('fastest')

# Set up the keybindings
screen.onkeypress(moveup, 't')
screen.onkeypress(movedown, 'g')
screen.onkeypress(shoot, '1')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

You'll note I made the program a bit more complicated by adding a timer but this allows you to aim your cannon while your bullet is hurling through the air, in preparation for your next shot.

Comment: could you please help explain about what how it works, because some parts are hard to understand. Thanks!